# can anyone please help me figure out this error i get in jupyter?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10412/3948216821.py in <module>
----> 1 data_scale_final ['cluster'] = y_km
      2 data_scale_final

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: What is `data_scale_final`?

Comment: `'cluster'` is a string, so it's not a valid index value. Maybe you meant to use `cluster`, without the quote marks, instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using data_scale_final[cluster] (without single quotes otherwise it is taking it as string). It depends on datatype of data_scale_final variable.